# Neo4j test container: Database name parameter for selecting database is not supported in Bolt Protocol Version 3.0

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-driver, neo4j-bolt

I'm using the Neo4j OGM and currently creating a session factory like this.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder()
                .uri(uri)
                .credentials(username, password)
                .database(db)
                .useNativeTypes()
                .build();

return new SessionFactory(config, Entity.class.getPackageName());
```

For my project I've created several unit tests which use the neo4j test container. By default the test container uses the community edition of neo4j. However, I need to use some feature from the neo4j enterprise edition. I therefore enable the `withEnterpriseEdition` option.

```
neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("neo4j:4.2.14-enterprise"))
                .withAdminPassword(password)
                .withEnterpriseEdition()
                .withReuse(true);
```

However, when running my unit test against the enterprise test container I get this exception:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Database name parameter for selecting database is not supported in Bolt Protocol Version 3.0. Database name: 'neo4j'

    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.beginTransaction(InternalSession.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.beginTransaction(InternalSession.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.newOrExistingNativeTransaction(BoltTransaction.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.<init>(BoltTransaction.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.lambda$null$0(BoltDriver.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:75)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.beginTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:530)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:580)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:558)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:429)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:424)
    at com.elsevier.rs.graph.models.service.SessionFactoryImplTest.queryCount(SessionFactoryImplTest.java:75)
    at com.elsevier.rs.graph.models.service.SessionFactoryImplTest.testForDatabase(SessionFactoryImplTest.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.request.MultiDatabaseUtil.assertEmptyDatabaseName(MultiDatabaseUtil.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v3.BoltProtocolV3.verifyDatabaseNameBeforeTransaction(BoltProtocolV3.java:176)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v3.BoltProtocolV3.beginTransaction(BoltProtocolV3.java:117)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.UnmanagedTransaction.beginAsync(UnmanagedTransaction.java:112)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.NetworkSession.lambda$beginTransactionAsync$6(NetworkSession.java:116)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.lambda$asCompletionStage$0(Futures.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$200(DefaultPromise.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:502)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the underlying Neo4j Java driver used by OGM is too old, so the OGM version is too old.
Because of that, the only Bolt protocol version that both the client and server can understand is version 3, which predates multi-tenancy support in Neo4j (it started with Neo4j version 4 and Bolt protocol 4.0).

Long story short: you should upgrade your OGM dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker just use this command else use neo4j 4.3 or above

username = neo4j
password = password

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
    -v $PWD/data:/data -v $PWD/plugins:/plugins \
    --name neo4j-apoc \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true \
    -e NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc"]' \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password \
    neo4j:4.3
```